# How to attach to existing Qt WebKit?

Tags: python, html, c++, qt, webkit

**As title said:**
    **how to attach to existing Qt WebKit by cross-process,
and get permission to control web page elements in Qt WebKit.**

1. existing Qt WebKit window[its hwnd is 123] in windows 7
2. i want to attach to the Qt WebKit window by hwnd[hwnd:123]
3. now,i can to control the loaded web page elements in Qt WebKit window;
   click web page button,get the hyperlink text and so on.

thank you!

Comment: Is there some reason you think this is possible?

Comment: it seams you try to build new `Selenium` module :)

Comment: This is not impossible, but will be very hard unless you use a library that was designed to let you take control of a Qt application. You pretty much have to use something like [Squish](http://www.froglogic.com/squish/gui-testing/) library to plug into the process and take over it. Reimplementing this from scratch is possible, but it's a lot of work.